# Using Managed Identity to connect to a queue from a WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-managed-identity

I have an app service with a system-assigned managed identity, and a WebJob operating off a queue trigger. If I give the app service an AzureWebJobsStorage connection string, it works, no problem. It grabs the message from the queue and does its stuff. But that's less secure, and thus far I've been unable to get it to work off the managed identity.

I have it using the following settings to provide the info it needs:

AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName: [my storage account name]

AzureWebJobsStorage__credential: ManagedIdentity

It should have everything it needs to use the storage account name and the name of the queue set in the queue trigger (plus permissions to the storage account on the managed identity, I've given it Contributor, Key Vault Secrets User and Storage Queue Data Contributor) to listen to the queue. But it doesn't give any indication that it's doing so. It doesn't give an error, either. It just says "Job host started".

Oh, and I have AzureWebJobsDashboard set, since it seems to be necessary to use the dashboard, but clearly it doesn't use that to interact with the queue.

If it makes any difference, the app service is Windows.

My questions are thus:

1. Is there something I'm missing that will get it working? Missing permissions, missing app settings, etc etc
2. Will it even work as a WebJob? Everything I've seen online mentions Function apps, and while there's a lot of crossover, strictly speaking, it's a WebJob, not a Function app. At least it's not defined as such in the Azure Portal.
3. If it won't work, what are the best alternatives? Previously we had connection strings coming from a Key Vault.

Comment: Which settings you want to secure?

Comment: Can you please share your Web Job Function code?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using connection strings. There's no need to share the code, it's just a regular .Net Core WebJob with a queue trigger. As I said, it works fine if I include the connection string in the app service overrides.

Comment: Will check from my end and let you know

Comment: Iam able to run the Web Job without connection string in `appsettings.json` file. We need to set the connection string in the `Program.cs` file itself to `ConfigureAppConfiguration` by retrieving the value from keyvault.

Comment: I'm trying to use Managed Identity, as that's the new standard. It's better than access keys since someone else could get a hold of the access key, and if it's invalidated, you'd need to replace the access key in the key vault. We can do that if there's no other option, I just need to make sure of that.

Comment: Please confirm once.. you don't want to store secrets in KeyVault ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the keys in Environment Variables.This is also a secure way.

Comment: Please confirm once.. Using managed identity u want to store keys and access the storage acc connection string..

Comment: If yes..Iam doing the same thing

Comment: I don't want to use a connection string at all. As in, I give it the storage account name, but no access key. Just authentication using the identity of the app service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256947/discussion-between-harshitha-and-pointlessspike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "None"
    }
  }  
}
```

Make sure you have set the LogLevel.

- Deployed the Web Job to Azure App Service.

[image]

- Enabled the Identity of Azure WebApp.

Thanks @[techcommunity](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/use-managed-identity-instead-of-azurewebjobsstorage-to-connect-a/bc-p/3921630/highlight/true#M1470) for the clear steps.

I have taken references from this blog and followed the same for WebApp.

- Add `AzureWebJobsStorage__accountname` setting in the Environment Variable with a value of your storage account name.

[image]

- In Storage account, you need to assign the below 3 role assignments for your WebApp.

```cs
Storage Account Contributor
Storage Blob Data Owner
Storage Queue Data Contributor
```

[image]

- Add a message in a Queue

[image]

and run the Web Job

[image]

***Output:***
[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to create the environment variable, but setting it as an app setting did the trick. I think I may have just been missing a role, but need to dig further into what is actually required. Thanks so much.